# ZF, Explicit default module directory; cant register Plugin

Tags: zend-framework, module, bootstrapping, zend-controller-plugin

I have several modules and also have moved the default module to the

```
modules/default
```

directory.

Every module has its Controller Plugins in each own

```
modulename/plugins
```

directory.

I do register those plugins in everys module own Bootstrap.

As far I have used for those plugins names which fits the pattern

```
ModuleName_Plugins_Name
```

and did created them for registration with

```
new ModuleName_Plugins_Name
```

I have several modules, each has its own plugin... Everything works just fine.

Now I wanted to add a plugin to the default module

```
modules/default/plugins/Name.php...
```

and register it in the application Bootstrap under

```
application/Bootstrap.php
```

but it says, my plugin class can not be found...

I am about to create a Bootstrap for my default plugin in its own module directory...
But would low to know what would be some other options for registering that plugin.

Thanks in advance.
kriscom

Answer (score 0):

Because ZF treats the default module a bit differently, it may be applying slightly different rules to how it looks up your default module plugins (since the standard practice is not to put the default module in your modules folder but rather in your application root).

You might have to add an additional configuration to the PluginLoader to set a Prefix/Path pair to match the plugin naming and location for your customized default module.

Try looking here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html